# Error in minikube installation on windows 7 enterprise

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to follow instructions on 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/

But I am getting an error on the command:

```
curl $(minikube service hello-minikube --url)
```

details below:

[image]

As you might have guessed I am a beginner, will appreciate if someone can guide me on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

```
curl $(minikube service hello-minikube --url)
```

is a bash command and when use on a bash prompt it executes `minikube service hello-minikube --url` and the output is passed to `curl`

Since you are using a Windows Command Prompt, you can run this first:

```
minikube service hello-minikube --url
```

Copy the output and then run:

```
curl <output>
```

Comment: In addition you can also use powershell if you need to use curl.